# PySpark GC issue - job taking more than 3 hrs to finish

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, garbage-collection, bigdata

I'm running spark application with only 5GB uncompressed csv files using 1 node 16gb machine, facing very high GC time, actual computation will take only 15 mins and 3hr+ for GC, what could be the possible solution to fix this issue.

[image]

Enabled below config but no improvement
spark.worker.cleanup.enabled
spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled

Comment: how complex are the transformations? they might be playing a role here.

Comment: what if you try to enable offheap `spark.memory.offHeap.enabled` and set `spark.memory.offHeap.size=some-gb` memory aside for it?

Comment: @samkart - yes there are very complex calculations, but in UI i can see the computations will finish with in 15 minutes,

Comment: @mazaneicha,  i'll try to enable offHeap  but how much gb is recommended, there are more chance to get offHeap OOM error

Comment: have lot of logging, print out completion of every step . add `.cache().count()` to every dataframe transformation.